# Alert de String Alterada

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var string = "Este aqui é o valor do cliente 000.000.00 01";
var str_subs = "129.000.000 02";
string = string.replace(/\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d \d\d/g, str_subs);

alert("Valor Original: " & ??????); -> No caso aqui eu deveria mostrar 000.000.00 01
alert("Valor Novo: " & str_subs);
```

Preciso mostrar o Valor ORIGINAL que o replace encontrou antes de alterar, como devo proceder?

Comment: Porquê sobrepôr o valor da variável? não pode dar nomes diferentes à versão original e à alterada? E já agora o caracter de concatenação em javascript é o `+`, tem de corrigir aqui: `alert("Valor Novo: " & str_subs);`

Comment: @Sergio, corrigi obrigado. Eu preciso pegar o valor que ele encontrou dentro da string, entende ? ou seja, o valor original.

Comment: E porque não fazer `var novaString= string.replace(/\d\ ....etc` e assim manter a variavel `string` com o valor original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia estar fazendo algo assim:

```js
var str = "Este aqui é o valor do cliente 000.000.00 01";
var old = str.match(/\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d \d\d/);
var to_replace = "129.000.000 02";
var new_str = str.replace(/\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d \d\d/g, to_replace);

alert("Valor Original: " + old);
alert("Valor Novo: " + to_replace);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2FLC/)

Comment: perfeito amigo, obrigado!